# Intercepting default behavior for form submission

Tags: jquery

When the following code executes, the parameters appear in the url, and no inner HTML within the table changes. The documentation says the default request method is a POST when data is provided.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var data = $(this).serializeArray();
    $('#items-table').load("drawer.php", data)
});
```

The `data` is outputted correctly as `MM=01&dd=01&yyyy=2001&HH=12&mm=00&ss=00&entername=Dr.+Clock&optionsRadios=option3&enteritemid=`, but it appears as parameters to the current page rather than the page identified in the load() function, `drawer.php`.

**EDIT**: Even when I use `serializeArray()` to make sure an object is passed as the second parameter to load() rather than a string, I still find that a GET request is called, and the current page's URL gains these parameters. The response from "drawer.php" does not appear in the div.

**SECOND EDIT**: It turned out I had failed to intercept the form's action, because I didn't include this line: `return false;` at the end of the submit function.

Comment: Where did you read this. I can't find that in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Comment: @François Wahl : wrong page, look here http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @Dr.Molle: Ah, I see. Thanks for the link, makes sense then. According to the docs, the `.serialize()` method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. That's probably why it fires the GET instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had failed to intercept the form's action, because I didn't include this line: `return false;` at the end of the submit function. Including this line solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise,
>   GET is assumed.

```
$('#items-table').load("drawer.php", {form_data:data})
```

So pass an `object/{}` instead of `string` because `serialize()` method creates a text string delimated with `&` and also you've used `$data` instead of `data`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `var data = $(this).serialize();`

The doc says:

> The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation.

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

You need to provide an object as the second parameter of load to use POST.